# notifying flask app of 'Connection reset by peer'

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I have a flask app that allows a user to download data from my server.
I'm using 'Response' and 'stream_with_context':

```
from flask import Response, stream_with_context

import requests
```

the final lines in my API are:

```
r = requests.get(url, stream=True, timeout=180, verify=ssl_context)
return Response(stream_with_context(r.iter_content(chunk_size=2048)), headers=headers)
```

The code works perfectly fine, but the problem is that Flask doesn't know if the user has cancelled the download or an interruption happened.
however, The log file shows the following if user cancels the download:

> uwsgi_response_write_body_do(): Connection reset by peer

but that's coming from ***nginx*** (I think) and I don't know how to trigger a function in flask if the interruption(cancellation) happens.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using

> @response.call_on_close

within

> @getfile_bp.after_request

something like:

```
@getfile_bp.after_request
def do_this_next(response):
   @response.call_on_close
   def print_message():
       print('download is completed or stopped')
```